# Laravel email sending not working when 'to' not overridden

Tags: laravel

Email sending works fine when I have a global 'to' set in config/mail.php

```
'to' => [
  'address' => 'someone@example.com',
   'name' => 'Someone',
```

however as soon as this is removed and email is supposedly sent to the actual email address, nothing happens. No errors, everything appears fine, except the email is never received.

I've checked spam folders, I've tried sending to different email addresses, I've tried setting the notifiable route (even though 'email' exists on the model), I've cleared cache and config cache, I've tried listening to message sending event and dumping results - I'm lost.

Comment: how are you building your message?

Comment: What transport are you using for mail - Sendmail or SMTP? You need to determine how far it is getting.

Comment: smtp.
building using notification with via 'mail'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved.

When sending a MailableObject (as apposed to a MailMessage) you need to chain the 'to' command like so:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailObject(blah blah))->to($notifiable);
}
```